# Include single quotes in concatenated string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to generate the comparison operands for an Oracle query using Javascript, but the query keeps showing the escape character everywhere I have a single quote. Any suggestions on how I can get around this would be much appreciated.

```
let compOperands = "to_date('" + (moment(timeStamp).format("D-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss") + "', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')");
```

Console:

`to_date('9-May-2017 06:41:54', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`

Once I concatenate it to another string, the escape characters show up:

`updateQuery = [(queries[queryName].query[0].concat(compOperands))];`

Console:

```
SELECT * FROM IVR_LZ_CALL_LEG WHERE START_TS > to_date(\'9-May-2017 06:32:32\', \'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss\')
```

EDIT:
ok I expanded this a little bit more and the addition of the characters seems to happen when the string is placed into an array. I refactored the concatenation above so I could step through what is going on in the console.

```
let updateQuery = [],
queryString = queries[queryName].query[0].concat(compOperands);

updateQuery.push(queryString);


 options.json.queries = updateQuery;
  console.log(queryString);
  console.log(updateQuery);
```

Console:

`SELECT * FROM IVR_LZ_CALL_LEG WHERE START_TS > to_date('9-May-2017 06:59:27', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
[ 'SELECT * FROM IVR_LZ_CALL_LEG WHERE START_TS > to_date(\'9-May-2017 06:59:27\', \'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss\')' ]`

Comment: That's just the way the string is visualized in your console by Node while `console.log` prints strings without escape characters. The escape characters aren't actually part of your string, neither in `compOperands` nor the concatenated string.

Comment: `console.log(updateQuery[0].indexOf('\\'));` returns -1, so @MikaelLennholm is right.